# Where and how long are values stored by user scripts persisted?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

Greasemonkey (and other user script managers) provide functions like `GM.getValue` and `GM.setValue` in its API, which allow scripts to store and retrieve arbitrary script-specific values.

[Greasemonkey’s documentation on `GM.setValue`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.setValue) promises that the values stored will persist across page loads and origins.  However, it’s pretty scant on other details, namely: how long are those values persisted?

- Until the tab is closed? (like `sessionStorage`)
- Until the browser is closed?
- Until browser cache is cleared? (like `localStorage`)
- Forever? (until the script and/or extension is removed)

Furthermore, with browser features like Firefox containers, should I expect values in user script storage to be available across different containers?

Finally, is there any way a user script can control how long/in which scope user script data is stored?

Comment: Forever (or until you remove/modify them).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: It uses [IndexedDB](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/efd22a93121225ada47f2fe9f021af0ab6100c21/src/bg/value-store.js#L19), so you can check the official docs. At the specs there is a section about the [durability](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#transaction-durability-hint). Also MDN has [some infos about the quota and eviction criterias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API/Storage_quotas_and_eviction_criteria#when_is_data_evicted) -- It's up to the environment how long the data persists.

Answer (score 2):

> how long are those values persisted?

UserScript managers store data permanently using [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (Greasemonkey) and [storage.StorageArea](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea) (FireMonkey, Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey).
Data is kept until userScript is deleted or userScript manager is uninstalled.

> Furthermore, with browser features like Firefox containers, should I expect values in user script storage to be available across different containers?

Firefox containers have no effect on userScript manager data storage.

Container affect Web storage API (data saved by a web page and tied to its domain).

> Finally, is there any way a user script can control how long/in which scope user script data is stored?

No. UserScripts can save data via `GM.setValue` or use Web storage API (not safe/secure as it can also be accessed by the web page).

Comment: ‘Firefox containers have no effect on userScript manager data storage.’ — have you checked? I did.

Comment: @user3840170 containers restrict data saved by a web domain. Data saved by user-script via `GM.setValue` are saved to the extension storage. Extension storage is not subject to containers. Containers (`cookieStoreId`) can be applied to certain GM APIs like download, XHR, fetch (for example FireMonkey does it), however, that is not storage. It mainly applies to cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

While @erosman gave a great answer and it is technically correct on the last point too, you can easily implement scoping/expiration yourself.
For simple scoping, add a scope-derived prefix to your keys.
For a more comprehensive implementation, store objects with whatever additional metadata fields you need, such as creation timestamp, scope or whatever in addition to a value key, then implement conditional access/pruning based on them.

[Someone with an account feel free to copy this as a comment to his answer, I am not going to create one just because of SO stupid policies about anon posts only allowed as answers and not comments. Or I guess mods can straight up delete this, hopefully after it's incorporated into his answer if you consider it useful]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34621473)